# How can I approximate the Rician Distribution through the Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Which are the techniques used to approximate a distribution into another? I know that I can model a Gaussian Distribution through the parameters of mean and variance. However how can I approximate Rice Distribution through the Gaussian Distribution? There is some good reference covering that?

Comment: In (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) "related distributions" you have 2 ways to simulate a Rice distribution.

Comment: Comment on revision: If you can generate standard normal observations $Z$ then $X = \sigma Z + \mu \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a Rayleigh distribution simply as:

```
    x_rayleigh = ( randn(1, 1e6) + 1i*randn(1, 1e6) ) / sqrt(2);
```

This is a complex normal distribution with zero mean and variance 1/2 per dimension. So the amplitude of x_rayleigh follows a Rayleigh distribution. The phase of x_rayleigh will be uniform.

Now if you add a line-of-sight component in the above random variable, the amplitude will be Rice distributed.

```
    x_rice = 1 + ( randn(1, 1e6) + 1i*randn(1, 1e6) ) / sqrt(2);
```

The histogram of the absolute value of the generated random variable is shown in the figure. [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Nash.

Comment: May you share where do you found this Rice relation? I would like a nice and detailed demonstration about what you did show here (as I requested by resources covering that on my original question). This seems really correct as I tested, but I'm not sure If I understand the reason correctly.

Comment: Well,  when you take the squared summation of two Gaussian random variables, that results in a Chi-square random variable with degrees of freedom equal to two (2) and when you take the square root of that Chi-square random variable (with dof = 2) becomes Rayleigh. This is what happens when you take the absolute value of a complex Gaussian random variable. Moreover, the definition says that if you add a line-of-sight component in a Rayleigh channel, it becomes Rician. You can refer to Chapter 4 of the book entitled "Fading and shadowing in wireless systems" by P. Mohana Shankar.

Comment: Really thank you! I did understand better now and thanks for the reference, I'll search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Center $(\mu_x, \mu_y) =(1,2)$ and standard deviation $\sigma=2.$
If you can generate univariate normal random variables $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(1,2)$
and  $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(1,2),$ then you have an uncorrelated bi-variate normal
distribution. Similarly, according to the Wikipedia article referenced by @JeanMarie, you can make various kinds of Rice distributions. Here is a plot using R.

```
x = rnorm(50000, 1, 2);  y = rnorm(50000, 2, 2)
plot(x, y, pch=".")
  abline(v=-10:10, col="lightblue")
  abline(h=-10:10, col="lightblue")
  abline(v=0, lwd=2, col="green2")
  abline(h=0, lwd=2, col="green2")
```

[image]

In order to get normal distributions from randomly generated
points in $(0,1)$ you can use the Box-Muller transform.
(See [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).)

Below a histogram suggests the shape of the density function of the distance of points from the origin, and a plot of
the corresponding empirical distribution function (ECDF) which approximates
the CDF. (Note: The ECDF sorts the $n$ points on the horizontal axis and 
increments by $1/n$ at corresponding points on the vertical axis)

```
d = sqrt(s^2 + y^2)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  hist(d, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  plot(ecdf(d))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

With this introduction in R and reference to the Wikipedia pages, you should be able to figure out how to do this
assignment using most any statistical or mathematical software.

Comment: This really helped me, @BruceET. Really thank you. However, can you point some good reference about this topic? The Wikipedia pages don't explain in details and I have some books of probability, random variable and statistics, but they just ignore that part.

Comment: Almost any post-calculus intro probability or mathematical statistics book should have what you need. One of hundreds, which I happen to have used for a class recently, is Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer: Math. statistics with Applications.  There are several editions, any of which should help.

Comment: @ManoelVilela.  Just saw edit. Thanks for fixing the typos.